# Matrix Calculus: product rule between row vector and square matrix with regards to a row vector of variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, tensors

## Problem:

I am very new to the world of matrix calculus. I am attempting to educate myself more on this vast topic. I am currently trying to tackle the following:

We have a row vector of shape $(1,M)$ and call it $\vec{\alpha}$. Furthermore, we have square matrix of shape $(M,M)$ and we call it $\mathbf{P}$. We assume that the entries of the vector and Matrix are functions of the parameters $\theta_i$. Hence, we have row vector of shape $(1,N)$ called $\vec{\theta}$.

I would like to compute the following:
$$\frac{\partial (\vec{\alpha}\mathbf{P})}{\partial \vec{\theta}}  $$

I am going to give this a go. I would like you to please confirm if what I have done is valid. Please, do keep in mind that my approach is that of someone who leans towards a computer science approach hence the solution might seem awkward to a Mathematician.

## My Attempt:

I assume that one can perform $\frac{\partial (\vec{\alpha}\mathbf{P})}{\partial \theta_i} $ for each $\theta_i$ separately. This would then result in a tensor of shape $(N,1,M)$. I will justify this shape shortly. Hence, we should have something that looks like this:

$$
\frac{\partial (\vec{\alpha}\mathbf{P})}{\partial \vec{\theta}} = \left[
\frac{\partial(\vec{\alpha}\mathbf{P})}{\partial \theta_1} ,\cdots,\frac{\partial(\vec{\alpha}\mathbf{P})}{\partial \theta_N} 
\right]
$$
This assumption would allow us to compute each of the $\frac{\partial(\vec{\alpha}\mathbf{P})}{\partial \theta_i} $ separately. This assumption is where either the success or downfall of the approach lies. Let us focus on a arbitrary entry of this tensor as we are going to use the product rule on it.

$$\frac{\partial(\vec{\alpha}\mathbf{P})}{\partial \theta_i}  =\frac{\partial \vec{\alpha} }{\partial \theta_i} \mathbf{P} + \vec{\alpha}\frac{\partial \mathbf{P}}{\partial \theta_i} $$

Seeing as $\theta_i$ is a scalar variable, we have don't have the scenario of things changing shape e.g. derivative of a vector by a vector gives a big Jacobian.

We thus conclude that $\frac{\partial(\vec{\alpha}\mathbf{P})}{\partial \theta_i} $ must be shape $(1,M)$ as we have matrix multiplication between a row vector and square matrix. This leads us to have a tensor with shape $(N,1,M)$. I will be discarding the second axis of size 1 to then form a $(N,M)$ shape matrix where each row of index $i$ contains all the entries with respect to $\theta_i$. I don't think it is perhaps necessary but would be convenient for coding.

## To end off:

Please help explain if it is a correct approach or not. If wrong, please explain why and guide me in the correct direction. I would appreciate this greatly.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Your logic is correct, but to avoid confusion in the future you shouldn't mix matrix and index notations. Full-blown index notation would substitute
$\partial_k\to\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_k},\,$
so the gradient calculation would look something like
$$
G_{kj} \doteq \partial_k(\alpha_iP_{ij})
  = (\partial_k\alpha_i)\,P_{ij} + \alpha_i\,(\partial_kP_{ij})
$$
Sticking with pure matrix notation, one often calculates differentials instead of gradients. For example, using the column vector $x=a^T$
$$y = P^Tx \quad\implies dy = dP^Tx + P^Tdx$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your confirmation. I also appreciate the very constructive advice that you have given to me regarding notation as well as the use of differentials. I am thinking of investing in a proper book to self study this. Is there a book that you have used which you might recommend? Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: The standard text is Magnus and Neudecker's "Matrix Differential Calculus"; I also like Hjorungnes's "Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives"; there's also an online PDF file titled "The Matrix Cookbook" compiled by Petersen and Pedersen; finally Dennis Bernstein's "Matrix Mathematics" is a collection of lots of generally useful matrix information.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your list of suggested texts. I shall investigate these.